# Where is the folder for assets?

Tags: java, android, csv, import

Simple Question I know - but my android app simply can´t find my CSV file. I´ve placed the file here:

[image]

and access it with this code:

```
public void getFragenfromCSV(){

        AssetManager a = getAssets();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            InputStream is =  a.open("fragenbronze.csv");
             reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                System.out.println(RowData[0]);

            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception
        }
        }
```

On running the app I always get the IOException from the catch part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to place it in

```
src/main/assets
```

never put something you want to keep in build/ as this get's removed with `clean`

Comment: Thank you very much! The folder hasn´t existing, that´s why I didn´t find it. After creating the folder it works. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome - if it solved the problem you might want to accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Project Structure with  assets folder

Answer (score 0):

You are going inside build but actually you have to go inside `src/main/assets`.